# Who are eligible to eat the Prasad?

Tags: scripture, vishnu, krishna, gods, prasad

> The food offered to God is called Naivedya while the sacred food sanctified and returned by God as a blessing is called Prasada

So who all can have the Prasad, Can someone who had non-veg eat it? Can a women during periods have it? Are there any restrictions for having the Prasad as per scriptures?

Comment: you should think that God decides who it is given - to whomever it is offered to. If the Lord appears to you and offers you non-veg prasad, will you refuse it because you are a vegetarian??

Comment: So you say it is no sin to give Prasad to everyone?

Comment: “If the Lord appears to you and offers you non-veg prasad, will you refuse it because you are a vegetarian??” <—— I’m vegan & animal liberation types, this would be a huge dilemma for me  I wouldn’t be able to eat it, would go against my beliefs so much. But thx for posting this comment @SwamiVishwananda Giving me something to think about ! Edit : I don’t think Devi Maa would make a vegan bhakt eat non-vegan prasad. So possibly then this will not happen I think. I hope never happens 